# Cannot load underlying module for 'PusherSwift' in Swift project

Tags: swift, pusherswift

I have tried almost everything possible in my knowledge and also tried using different versions of PusherSwift as well.

Using older versions of `PusherSwift`, cause same error for `CryptoSwift`.

I have converted my code to Swift 5 as well. But still facing this error.

`PusherSwift` version: 8.0.0

[image]

`PusherSwift` is added automatically in Build Phase

[image]

[image]

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, :deployment_target => "9.0"

 #use_frameworks!
def shared_pods
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.25.0'
#pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23.3'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.10.1' # using an older version to avoid a bug https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/95982788
pod 'MPFoldTransition'
pod 'UICKeyChainStore'
pod 'JCNotificationBannerPresenter'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'IGHTMLQuery'
pod 'Fabric', '~>  1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.14'
pod 'OpenTok', '~>  2.16.3'
pod 'PusherSwift'

end
```

Comment: Can you share your pod file?

Comment: I have added Podfile @VinayakaSY